# Detecting pause in sound bytes from microphone in Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, audio, flutter-dependencies

I came across this plugin -- https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream -- on pub.dev while searching for a solution to listen to microphone from a flutter app (targeted for both android and iOS).

I am able to use this plugin to listen to user utterances from the microphone as well as playback audio when needed in my app. The requirements are as follows:

1. Listen to user utterances from the microphone,
2. Convert the audio byte stream received from the microphone into a base64 encoded string,
3. Send the audio string to a service by calling a REST API (POST),
4. Optionally, if the service responds back with audio (in form of a base64 encoded string), decode the audio output string, and play back the sound bytes.

All of these steps are working fine -- both on Android and iOS. However, in the MVP, I don't know how to detect a pause in user utterances (in the audio stream received from the microphone) and automatically trigger the REST API call. Currently my app requires the user to toggle the microphone button on and off in order to talk and then send their audio to the service. So, the user currently needs to tap on the microphone button (on my app) to activate the RecorderStream of the sound_stream plugin, speak and tap on the microphone button again to turn off the RecorderStream and at this point my app calls the API. It's like those walkie-talkies of the good old days!

I want to avoid this and seamlessly call the API when I detect a pause in the user speech and send the sound bytes received until then to the service. Any idea on how I might be able to achieve this?

Any tips will be highly appreciated.